# F#: Two Dimensional Array - Generate all possible binary combinations

Tags: matrix, f#, permutation

What approach would you use to generate the set of NxN matrices containing only zeros and ones which represents all possible distinct combinations?

```
let matrix Array2D.init N N (fun x y -> something)
```

If you don't know F# then pseudocode will be a contribution aswell.

So what I want is a list/array of all the distinct matrix combinations

Comment: "All possible distinct combinations" of what? I don't understand what you're looking for. Perhaps you could give an example of a 3x3 or 4x4 matrix that shows the result you want to get; that might make it clearer how to answer your question.

Comment: Lets say you have an array of 2 elements. For binary inputs there is 4 diffrerent combinations. [1,1] [1,0] [0,1] [0,0]. Now consider a NxN matrix

Comment: So in each slot in the 2x2 matrix, you want a list like [1;1], or [0;1] and so on. Okay, but what about a 3x3 matrix. There are **eight** combinations of three binary digits (000 through 111), but there are *nine* places in a 3x3 matrix. I can see filling in eight of the nine places with one of the eight combinations of three binary digits, but what goes in the ninth slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think the hard part is the generating the list of elements. We can do it recursively.

The base case is easy. For a 1x1 matrix, you have 1 element which can only have two combinations: `[|[|0|]; [|1|]|]`.

For a 2x2 elements, we have 2^2 = 4 elements. Each one of these can be either 1 or 0, so there are 2^4 = 16 combinations possible. To get all the combinations possible for this 2x2 array, we can think of it as an array of length 4.

But first, let's think about an array of length 2. Then we have to find all the combinations between `[|[|0|]; [|1|]|]` and `[|[|0|]; [|1|]|]`. This would be `[|[|0; 0|]; [|0;1|]; [|1;0|]; [|1; 1|]|]`. Luckily, there's a function called `Array.allPairs` which will generate the array of all possible combinations between two arrays, which already does this for us!

So, we can apply `Array.allPairs` to each element of our array of length 4 sequentially to get all the possible combinations for the entire matrix using `Array.reduce`. I make a function called `pairsToArray` to basically flatten the data structure.

```
let pairsToArray x = Array.concat [|fst x; snd x|]

let rec binary N = 
    match N with
    | 0 -> [||]
    | 1 -> [|[|0|]; [|1|]|]
    | n -> let elements = n*n
           let combinations = Array.init elements (fun i -> binary 1)
           let result = Array.reduce (fun acc i -> Array.allPairs acc i |> Array.map pairsToArray) combinations
           result
```

Now, all that remains is converting this to a `Array2D`. 
Something like should do the trick

```
let c = binary 2
c |> Array.map (fun i -> Array2D.init 2 2 (fun j k -> i.[j+k*2]))
```

for the 2x2 case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
let rec addOne (N1: int, N2: int) (M: int[,]) (i: int, j: int)=
  if M.[i,j] = 0
   then M.[i,j] <- 1
        true
   else M.[i,j] <- 0
        let newi, newj =
            if i < N1-1
             then (i+1,j)
             else (0,j+1)
        if newj = N2
         then false
         else addOne (N1, N2) M (newi,newj)
```

combined with this

```
let N = 3
let M: int[,] = Array2D.zeroCreate N N
let mylist =
  [ yield M;
    while addOne (N,N) M (0,0)
       do yield Array2D.copy M ]
```

I don't know if it makes sense.
It is a method to find the "next" matrix, and then make a list of all the matrices that we encounter that way.

edit: replaced bool with int (0 and 1) to better fit the original question.